# Use iOS 10.3.3 with Xcode Version 8.2.1?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, version

I am using Xcode Version 8.2.1 and cannot upgrade because I am working off of a 2008 MBP and the latest versions of Xcode are not supported.

I trying to run a project on an iPhone 5 which is running iOS 10.3.3 however, when i try to run the project from Xcode I get the following error message:

[image: error message]

I checked the device support folder located at:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

and I see that the 10.3 folder is not present

[image: device support]

Is there a way I can add a folder for 10.3 device support? Is there a place I can download it and add it into my Xcode?

If this is not possible, does anyone know a way to downgrade to an unsigned iOS firmware such as 10.2 or lower?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41928402/4935811

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can download the Xcode 8.3 separately(or get it from here :https://gist.github.com/steipete/d9b44d8e9f341e81414e86d7ff8fb62d#gistcomment-2041802) and get the 10.3 SDK from that which resides in Developer/Platforms directory. Reboot system as well as XCode and select SDk in settings as 10.3

Comment: Thank you so much! I simply downloaded the 10.3 folder from your link and pasted it in the DeviceSupport file and it worked like magic!

Comment: Do you know if one exists for iOS 11? I'm running the beta on one of my phones @Joe

Comment: iOS 11 is a different world, I don't think we can support that with Xcode 8.2. For that you need to have Xcode 9 beta and if you have not yet downloaded, download it and see the new Avatar of Simulators :)

Comment: No I was just saying about in built Simulators of Xcode 9 beta its completely changed. Nope you will need atleast  OS X 10.12 to run Xcode 9 beta

Comment: Is it possible to use iOS 10.3.3 in the simulator though?  Or will it just be the first iteration (10.3)?

Comment: I get the following error when I try to run on a device with 10.3.3 "App installation failed - A signed resource has been added, modified, or deleted." Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your Xcode with 8.3 or later or download .dmg file from here 
https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: I downloaded Xcode 8.3, which then required MacOS 10.13.  However 10.13 won't run the downloaded Xcode 8.3 because "the identity of the developer (apple.com) cannot be confirmed".  Selecting "Open Anyway" in System Preferences didn't help.  I don't really want to go to Xcode 9 because of so many negative reviews.  Any thoughts?